# Add $scope.watch inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html page which calls the controller and directive at page refresh. So when I edit the id, the `$scope.watch` in the controller checks for the value change and updates certain field but the directive is not called. So the html page shows old values and not the updated values, unless page refreshed.

I added `$scope.watch` in the directive but it is loaded only when the page is refreshed.

So how can I track the change and then call the function in the directive?

My controller and directive are in two different js files.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There's no reason you can't use a watch in a directive.

Comment: Can u show your code ?